# Symfony 2 : access to form config and submitted data in PRE_SUBMIT event

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I'm currently trying to access to my form config (and its options) in a PRE_SUBMIT FormEvent callback. However, when I'm doing that for example :

```
<?php
// This is my callback function for the PRE_SUBMIT event on a formtype element
public function preSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    $data = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();
    [...]
    $myConfig = $form->get('my_form_element_child')->getConfig()->get('my_option');
?>
```

It raises an exception saying :

> FormBuilder methods cannot be accessed anymore once the builder is turned into a FormConfigInterface instance.

Actually, I can understand why : it is because the form data is going to be submitted.
However, it is a problem for me. Indeed, I need to find a way to create other fields in my form based on some config options, when the data is **already** entered by the user but before the data gets "handled" by the controller.

Any idea on how to do that?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace

`$myConfig = $form->get('my_form_element_child')->getConfig()->get('my_option');`

to

`$myConfig = $form->get('my_form_element_child')->getConfig()->getOption('my_option');`